# Different css position top between the browsers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have some trouble with the positioning of my mobile menu.

It seems that chrome has a small shift from 1px then in the other browser and Ι don't know why. Αs well Firefox looks in a specific width range good, but not overall. Ι use bootstrap and bootstrap use noramlize.css to reset the elements.

Ι prepared it on jsfiddle and tried to figure out what the problem is but was not able to.

Ηere you can better see what Ι mean: [image]

Ι use the normal `navbar` from bootsrap:

HTML

```
<div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top-nav" aria-expanded="true">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="hamburger-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div style="" aria-expanded="true" class="navbar-collapse collapse in" id="top-nav">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-top">
                                <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-btn small" type="button" href="reseller.php">
                                        <span class="icon reseller-icon"></span><span class="text">Reseller</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-btn small" type="button" href="first_step.php">
                                        <span class="icon wizard-icon"></span><span class="text">Data capturing</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                     <a class="dropdown-btn small" type="button" href="settings.php">
                                        <span class="icon settings-icon"></span><span class="text">Settings</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="dropdown-btn small" type="button" href="archive.php">
                                        <span class="icon archive-icon"></span><span class="text">Archive</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="modalbox dropdown-btn small" href="#modalbox-language-country">
                                        <span class="icon search-icon"></span><span class="text">Language / Country</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="visible-xs">
                                    <a class="dropdown-btn small" href="#">
                                        <span class="icon"></span><span class="text">Logout</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Due the css is not that small, it may be better to see it directly on jsfiddle.

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/nm7b8jw2/5/

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok i add a image to my description

Comment: Ok...a **Minimal** demo is required. There's WAY too much code there to wade through.

Comment: are you using the same device to check ? the same zoom on the page ?

Comment: @Paulie_D what do you mean with demo? what is still not clear?

Comment: @jeremy-denis yes, i'm using same device, windows 10 machine, just different browsers an yes same zoom on the page or better say, no zoom

Comment: You have way too much irrelevant CSS in there....don't copy you whole CSS file, just the post the relevant parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue occurs because Firefox renders the `.navbar-header` element with a height of **31px** where as in Chrome the element is rendered with a height of **30px**.

Such issues usually are handled by tweaking the `line-height` property of the elements. With two changes in the CSS it can be aligned in all browsers.

One is:

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    body {
      font-size: 13.5px;
      line-height: 20px; } } /* Line 17: previous value was 19px */
```

The second is:

```
  header .nav-top-wrapper .navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 10px;  /* Line 279: previous value was 5px 0 4px 10px */
    font-size: 19px; }
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/4vwsjdhb/) is a working demo.